# What is the origin of the asctime format?

Tags: c++, c, datetime

Why was the particular character representation that the `asctime` function returns, i.e. `Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy\n`, chosen and what is its origin? The ordering of the information seems peculiar to me, especially putting the time information in between the date information. Is this (or was this) a common datetime representation in the US?

Comment: A good question, and well received. Too late now, but maybe it ought to have been asked at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: There might be pushback with regards to Retro.SE. Computing history questions are on-topic (at least until or unless a Computer History SE starts) but in general those systems that are still _technically_ in use in modern systems are off-topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This come directly from C. Probably the year was added later. Also the `\n` is strange. Probably a convenience function when building UNIX, and it got standardized by use.

Note: the function is "obsolete", and possibly it will be removed in later version of C. It is replaced by more powerful `strftime()`.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/asctime.html) has no rationale about the choice.

[ESR](http://www.catb.org/esr/time-programming/) wrote:

> In older Unixes the following functions were available to report time and date as a string. They wired in bad design choices (the date string is of unpredictable length and includes a trailing "\n"), are not locale-aware, and have undefined behavior for years before 0 or after 9999.

We have also few information from 7th edition of the manual (1979) [see manual pages](https://s3.amazonaws.com/plan9-bell-labs/7thEdMan/vol1/man3.bun.txt).

[Somebody (Clive D.W. Feather)](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2004-July/012564.html) looked for the same information as you (but directly to C standard group), but I do not find the answer. Just that C99 were corrected because some imprecision [email on the same thread](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2004-August/012580.html).

I think it will be difficult to get more information.

Comment: See also http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/dr_217.htm by the same person.

Comment: I find `ctime()`, which provides the same format here: https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/Dennis_v5/v5man.pdf  Intersting enough it mentions that `ctime()` existed (and still does exist) for Fortran as well. So I can imagine that the format had just been borrowed, as Fortran is elder then C.

Comment: @alk: the FORTRAN ctime is number of second since 1970 (and the manual say it is more like time()). Probably it was noted that it is not nice to have the same name for two function so the function was renamed to asctime). [page 177]

Comment: @MSalters: that seems strange (and interesting): similar bug, same person, but your link is about 4 year earlier then the second discussion.

Comment: The POSIX rationale seems to be "we included it because it's in the C standard (but we're marking it as obsolete as a hint that you shouldn't use it)".

Comment: [V3's `ctime`](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V3/man/man3/ctime.3) had no year in the output, and a BUGS note: `The routine must be reassembled for leap year.` (Note "assembled" not "compiled" - there was no C yet.) [V4's `ctime`](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V4/man/man3/ctime.3) added the year and the newline.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Not that strange. The ISO C committee has always been pretty small. You're likely to bump into the same names.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a common representation in the US, and the C Rationale even admits as much:

> **7.11 Localization**
>
> ....
>
> **Date and time.** The standard function `asctime` returns a string which
>   includes abbreviations for month and weekday names, and returns the
>   various elements in a format which might be considered unusual even
>   in its country of origin.

In hindsight, it's one of those functions that never should have made it into a Standard. The lack of a Rationale justifying its inclusion is a clear sign of that.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to the C Rationale?